# Vue 3 sorting - this.lists.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, sorting

Vue 3 front-end template:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <router-link to="/user/create" class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5">Add New</router-link>  
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <button @click="sortBy('email')">Sort by email</button>
                <button @click="sortBy('username')">Sort by Name</button>
                <tr v-for="(item, index) in lists" :key="index">
                    <td scope="row">{{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.username}}</td> 
                    <td>{{ item.email}}</td>
```

My method for sorting.

```
 data() {
    return {
      lists: [], //filled in firebase by /get route
    };
 methods: {
       sortBy(prop) {
      this.lists.sort((a,b) => a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 1)
    },
```

When i try to click on a sort button by email or username i'm receiving the error sorts is not a functions.

Comment: runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:217 Uncaught TypeError: this.lists.sort is not a function
    at Proxy.sortBy (list.vue?a7a7:52)
    at Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (list.vue?a7a7:14)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:301)

Comment: The error means `this.lists` is not an array. Since the question shows it as one, the problem is either one of the syntax errors in your question or probably you set it incorrectly when returning the database results

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the braces you opened for data() {}

```
 data() {
    return {
      lists: [], //filled in firebase by /get route
    };
},
 methods: {
       sortBy(prop) {
      this.lists.sort((a,b) => a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 1)
    },
```

Comment: nope, this was a copy mistake. the syntax is correct